# Nested IEnumerators not running as I expect

Tags: c#, ienumerator

If I call `Run()` multiple times, I expect to see the messages "One", "Two" and "Three", but it's not what is happening, I can see the first one and then the `MoveNext()` returns false. What am I missing here?

```
public class Test
{
    private IEnumerator<Object> routine;

    public void Setup()
    {
        routine = CountOne();
    }
    
    public void Run()
    {
        routine.MoveNext();
    }
    
    private IEnumerator<Object> CountOne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("One");
        yield return CountTwo();
    }

    private IEnumerator<Object> CountTwo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Two");
        yield return CountThree();
    }

    private IEnumerator<Object> CountThree()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Three");
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this Unity? If yes - please add appropriate tag.

Comment: does not matter, you just need to change the prints, the question is about a c# feature not something specific to unity

Comment: Yes it does, in "vanilla" C#  this will not even compile

Comment: Edited for plain C#, sorry

Answer (score 2):

It might help to better understand things if you avoid using `Object`:

```
public class Test
{
    private IEnumerator<int> routine;

    public void Setup()
    {
        routine = CountOne();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        routine.MoveNext();
    }

    private IEnumerator<int> CountOne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("One");
        yield return CountTwo(); // Cannot implicitly convert type ...
    }

    private IEnumerator<int> CountTwo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Two");
        yield return CountThree(); // Cannot implicitly convert type ...
    }

    private IEnumerator<int> CountThree()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Three");
        yield return 0;
    }
}
```

This will have a few compile-time errors when you try to `yield return CountTwo();` or `yield return CountThree();`. That's because these functions return `IEnumerable<int>`s and you're only allowed to `yield return` an `int` from a method returning an `IEnumerator<int>`.

That error wasn't happening in your original code because technically an `IEnumerator<Object>` *is* an `Object` and can be cast as one, even though that's not the intent you had when you `yield return`ed.

To get the behavior you're looking for, change these from `yield return` to just `return`, or create a `foreach` loop to `yield return` *each item* in the IEnumerator returned from those methods.

Comment: The object enumerator was intended correctlt. My point isnt about what I'm yielding to, my point is that it should yield to inner ienumerator method as this is the return of the first method and then yield to the third object as this is the return of the second, but this isn't what is happening and I not getting why

Comment: @Nefisto, when you call `Run`, you are enumerating the enumerator created by `CountOne` method and only it. When you execute `yield return CountTwo();`, its result is returned as the `Object` value of the `IEnumerator<Object>`. Since `CountOne` doesn't have loops or additional `yield return` statements, your enumerator is completed and doesn't execute anything else.

Comment: @Nefisto if you add the following line at the end of the `Run` method, it will enumerate the enumerator returned by the `CountTwo` next time you call `Run`: `routine = (IEnumerator<Object>)routine.Current;`

Comment: Hey @Artur, good catch, a guy has pointed me in another forum that the problem was just that I've nothing to call the move next to the returned object from CountTwo, so ur solution make sure that I will call the MoveNext for other objects. This trigger a lot of other problems =D but it solves this one, thanks for sharing

Comment: @Nefisto this is not a solution but just a hack to explain what happens there. Try to describe the problem you are trying to solve and we will try to give you a better solution. Because your code definitely should be rewritten.

Comment: @Nefisto: I understand that you want an `object` enumerator. But by changing the type in your sample code, you can see why your code isn't behaving the way you think it will. Try replacing `yield return CountTwo();` with `foreach(var twoResult in CountTwo()) yield return twoResult;`

Comment: @StriplingWarrior thanks for the suggestion, as I said on the other answer consuming the enumerator will give the expected behaviour, but this is just a small sample of the issue, originally this runs inside a second layer that controls the routine. But the point here is more to understand why this was happening, now that I know I can try to approach it in a different way

Comment: @Nefisto: Does my answer help you to understand why this was happening? That is my objective.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this comes from Unity and I have not worked with it for a while, but try enumerating the enumerators:

```cs
public class Test
{
    private IEnumerator routine;
    
    public void Run()
    {
        routine ??= CountOne();

        while (routine.MoveNext())
        {
            // no-op
        }
    }
    
    private IEnumerator CountOne()
    {
        Debug.Log($"One");
        var countTwo = CountTwo();
        while (countTwo.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return countTwo.Current;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator CountTwo()
    {
        Debug.Log($"Two");
        var countThree = CountThree();
        while (countThree.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return countThree.Current;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator CountThree()
    {
        Debug.Log($"Three");
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Otherwise in `CountOne` you just return a single item which is the next enumerator without actually processing it (i.e. return type of `CountOne` is effectively`IEnumerator<IEnumerator>`).

`yield return` supports returning `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerable` interchangeably. And from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/yield#execution-of-an-iterator):

> The call of an iterator doesn't execute it immediately...

> ... when you start to iterate over an iterator's result, an iterator is executed until the first yield return statement is reached. Then, the execution of an iterator is suspended and the caller gets the first iteration value and processes it. On each subsequent iteration, the execution of an iterator resumes after the yield return statement that caused the previous suspension and continues until the next yield return statement is reached. The iteration completes when control reaches the end of an iterator or a yield break statement.

Comment: I've edited my code for plain C#, sorry for it.

Comment: @Nefisto NP. This does not change much for "plain" or Unity. Try the answer.

Comment: Consuming the enumerator (as you are doing) makes it runs as expected, but my point is that IMK when I yield to an enumerator it should yield for the inner return, but this isn't what happen, I just want to know why

Comment: @Nefisto what do you mean by _"should yield for the inner class"_?

Comment: Typo, I mean the inner method that is being returned by the outer method

Comment: @Nefisto this is how enumerators work. This is not a simple method call. Compiler will actually wrap it in state machine and the actual method execution will be on the first `MoveNext()`. Enumerators a lazy.

Comment: Okay but why the MoveNext would not stop on the inner yield inside CountTwo?

Comment: @because everything until `yield return` is executed. Added quote from docs (and link).

Answer (score -1):

What's going on here is `yield` keyword messes with the declared return types of the methods.

When we put `yield` in a method declared to return `IEnumerator<Object>`, it expects the result of the `yield` expressions to be **`Object`**. If we put `yield` in a method declared to return `IEnumerator<string>`, (a la "One", "Two", "Three"), it expects the results of the `yield` expressions to be **`string`** (not `IEnumerator<string>`!

*But that's not what you have.* Instead, the nested `CountTwo()` and `CountThree()` methods also return `IEnumerator` types, and the only reason the original code compiles at all is those types are assignable to `Object`.

It's also important that these are three different enumerators, and not three yields in the same enumerator. When the code first calls `Run()`, only the `CountOne()`'s enumerator is involved, at which point it is completed, since it only has the one element.

> If I call Run() multiple times, I expect to see the messages "One", "Two" and "Three"

Let's make that happen! Here are two examples:

```
public class Test
{
    private IEnumerator routine;
    
    public void Setup()
    {
        routine = (new string[] {"One", "Two", "Three"}).GetEnumerator();
    }
    
    public void Run()
    {
        routine.MoveNext();
        Console.WriteLine(routine.Current);
    }
}

// Designed to look more like the original
public class Test2
{
    private IEnumerator routine;
    
    public void Setup()
    {
        routine = CountOne();
    }
    
    public void Run()
    {
        routine.MoveNext();

        // queue up the next enumerator
        routine = (IEnumerator)routine.Current;
    }
    
    public IEnumerator<IEnumerator<IEnumerator<string>>> CountOne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("One");
        yield return CountTwo();
    }
    
    public IEnumerator<IEnumerator<string>> CountTwo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Two");   
        yield return CountThree();
    }
    
    public IEnumerator<string> CountThree()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Three");
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

See them work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/08hfBz

Comment: @Artur I haven't read any other answers yet. I've been playing with the fiddle link at the bottom, because the behavior was a little surprising to me at first, as well (You can see my initial thoughts in the edit history).

Comment: I might be wrong in my judgment, but the timing of the edits gives another impression.